# Is this grammatically correct? "For one, I had mainly be"

Tags: grammaticality

Is the following grammatically correct?

> The introduction of this assignment had made me rethink many previous ideas that I had held on to in previous assigned projects. *For one, I had mainly* been using Illustrator to...

Comment: For one, I had mainly been...

Comment: @RegDwight - I added it to my answer. I made it a comment, as it was not about the main concern of the OP.

Comment: I like the sound of "previously assigned projects" more than "previous assigned projects", but I think they are both grammatically correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is correct, as *for one* references back to *ideas*. See [here](http://www.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/forone.html):

> People often say “for one” when they mean “for one thing”: “I really want to go to the movie. For one, Kevin Spacey is my favorite actor.” (One what?) The only time you should use “for one” by itself to give an example of something is when you have earlier mentioned a class to which the example belongs: “There are a lot of reasons I don’t want your old car. For one, there are squirrels living in the upholstery.” (One reason.)

Additionally, as I commented on the question, it would be

> For one, I had mainly been...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the been* mistake. Wasn't really paying attention to the paragraph at the time I wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

"I had mainly been" is fine, in the context you're using it.  I might question whether or not the "mainly" adds any useful information.

However, in the first sentence, instead of "had" I would use "has".  The introduction has, in the present, made you rethink previously held ideas.  Saying "The introduction had made me rethink" seems to indicate you're saying something about a change of mind in the past.  That may be what you meant, in which case I suggest taking out the "had" altogether -- "the introduction made me rethink".

The third "had" in those two sentences is OK, I think.  However, I'd suggest removing the "on to", i.e. "rethink many previous ideas that I had held in previous assigned projects".  Also, when you're saying that you are rethinking ideas, the context indicates that they are no longer ideas you hold now.  So, you can remove the first "previous".  "... rethink many ideas I had held in previous assigned projects."

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the first "had" - you mean to imply that you were using Illustrator until the introduction of the assignment, so using *had* in both cases fails to grammatically convey that point.

> The introduction of this assignment made me rethink many previous
>   ideas that I had held on to in
>   previous assigned projects. For one, I
>   had mainly been using Illustrator to...